# How to stop Visual Studio from putting extra newline at the end of a file on save

Tags: visual-studio, editor

I'm using `Visual Studio 2019`, and when I save a file (a `cs` file for example) VS will put an extra newline at the of the file.

1. I need to stop this behavior, but what I have searched on the internet so far, was about `visual studio code` or editors other than `Visual Studio`.
2. What is the philosophy of putting an extra newline at the end of file?

Comment: for question 1: _why_? what problems does it cause for you? for question 2: [this has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/encodings-and-line-breaks?view=vs-2019) link, I need to make `Advanced Save Options` menu visible, and then click it and change `line endings` dropdown value from `Current Settings` to `Windows (CR LF)`.

Comment: I tried this but clicking the okay button on the Advanced Save Options menu doesn't change anything.